# Add base url to all images in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a JavaScript editor called NicEdit which doesn't come with an option to change or reference the base URL. I was wondering if this can be done in jQuery or JavaScript?

The image src of all images in the DIV element are the same, `<IMG border=0 src="/image.jpg">` except the actually images is stored under a different domain and directory altogether.

I like the `src` to remain `/image.jpg`, but make reference to all images into fully-qualified URLs like `http://www.domain.com/image.jpg` within the that DIV only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not too difficult with jQuery, but the kind of thing you should consider doing server-side so that your links don't all break when JS is turned off.

```
$("#div img").each(function (i, e) {
  $(e).attr("src", "http://www.domain.com/" + $(e).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this allows external images to exist and not be affected (not a very deep check though)

```
$( 'img' ).not( '[src*="://"]' ).each( function( )
{
    $( this ).attr( 'src', 'http://whatevs.com' + $( this ).attr( 'src' ) ); }
} );
```

Comment: Please learn to follow convention. **Nobody** writes code like this, with spaces after ever bracket/brace. It's an absolute eye-sore, and you coworkers will hate you for it.

Comment: } braces is extra.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work:

```
   $('#divid img').each(function() {
       var newsrc = 'http://www.domain.com' + $(this).attr('src');
       $(this).attr('src', newsrc)
    })
```

Comment: Better put `$(this)` in a variable.